# Epub or Mobi Sdk for xamarin

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, epub, ebook-reader

I am thinking of developing Ebook reader in xamarin forms. But I could not find any Epub/Mobi reader SDK anywhere.Is there any xmarin SDK available for Ebook reader ? If it is not available , How can I develop one in xamarin ?

Comment: did you get anything on it?

Comment: @Apurv no.There are some Nuget for epub. I am yet to explore them.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. Please share the findings. I am also looking into it. If I will receive something from my end, will let you know.

Comment: @DevaPalanisamy : did you get anything for E Readers for Xamarin

Answer (score 2):

I have made a port of EpubReader for PCL projects: [EpubReader.Cross](https://github.com/g0rdan/EpubReader.Cross).
It has almost same api except you need to use streams instead paths to files.
You can download the library as a package from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EpubReader.Cross): `Install-Package EpubReader.Cross`

For opening a book without loading content:

```
var epubBook = EpubReader.OpenBook(stream);
```

For reading a book:

```
var epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(stream);
```

Comment: Does this work for xamarin.android or Xamarin.ios? Thank you.

Comment: @IshworKhanal Sure. It works for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS as well. Just try to install the package to your projects.

Comment: Can I use this without MVVM framework in xamarin.android? Because the app I have built is without MVVM framework. Thank you.

Comment: @IshworKhanal Of course. This library works only in "PCL area". It doesn't have any relations with MVVM frameworks. You have only one issue, you need to convert book file to stream and put that into the library. The library doesn't know how to works with IO (because it's PCL, cross platform)

Comment: You mean, I have to first download the file in device and return its stream like ` private Stream TestStream()
    {
        Stream fs = File.OpenRead("testdocument.epub");
        return fs;
    }  EpubBook epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(TestStream());

` and then use your library to read

Comment: @IshworKhanal Correct.

Comment: If I am not wrong, does this library have only plain epub file reading feature but not UI features like text highlighting, insertion notes, night mode etc?

Comment: @IshworKhanal Yes, it has only reading epub files feature. UI features are more platform specific things.

Comment: does it support pdf or only epub file to read??

Comment: @IshworKhanal Unfortunately, only ePub

Answer (score 0):

Just checked few nugets with following results:

- ePub

  - epubsharp
    netfx3.5 - so no go for Xamarin. Besides this is only for generation of epub format
  - epubfactory
    PCL - this might work for Xamarin.Forms
  - epubreader 
    I was not able to determine tartget platform. Try adding to the project
- Mobi - none found

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one - https://epubear.scand.com/. It stands for Xamarine as well as for Android & iOS. Fairly faster than SkyEpub, not buggy and doesn't remind me of construction set with lots of unuseful features & tools. Reliable, easy to drive and the team is fast to respond in case you might need help.

Comment: Please don't just post some links or library as an answer. At least demonstrate how it solves the problem in the answer itself.